# What does it mean for N to be small compared to the overall size of the collection?

Tags: python-3.x, heapq

I'm new to python-3x and I'm having a hard time understanding what it means for N to be smaller compared to the overall size of the collection:
"If you are looking for the N smallest or largest items and N is small compared to the overall size of the collection, these functions provide superior performance. Underneath the covers, they work by first converting the data into a list where items are ordered as a heap." https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch01.html

Comment: It sounds like you are quoting something you read in some documentation.  Can you include a link to it so that we can see the context?  It sounds like you are asking about a Big-O statement, but can't be sure without context.

Comment: "If you only want a small portion of the items out of all the items you have."